# Getting SubItem from listview

Tags: c#, listview, c++-cli

I am trying to get Subitem from a list view, I did this but doesn't work:

```
curItem1=listView2->Items[i]->Text;

curItem2=listView2->SubItem[i]->Text;
```

Comment: Should be something like this: `listView2->Items[i]->SubItems[y]->Text`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListViewItem selItem = listView1.Items[i];
string txt = selItem.SubItems[index].Text;
```

To get the `Text` is wrong in first line.

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the Text property of a certain control inside the ListViews ItemTemplate. This is done similarly to this:

```
string curItem = ((TextBox)listView2.Items[i].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```

Where 'TextBox1' is the control you are trying to get the Text property of. You also need to make sure that you are casting to the correct type of the Control you are trying to get the property for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... `ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(i).Text`