# How can I have all the elements of a list view row?

Tags: c#, listview, contextmenu

I have the following list view:
[image: listview]
and I have put a context menu there so that I can right click on a row

```
 private void listView1_MouseClick_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                if (listView1.FocusedItem.Bounds.Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
                }

            }
        }
```

Now in this context menu I have

```
 private void retryPackToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //I have to have the content somewhere
            Trace.WriteLine(listView1.SelectedItems[0].ToString());

        }
```

However the `listView1.SelectedItems` only have the first column (Date) but I can not manage a way to get the other columns values (Pack Number, paper Width)
Can somebody help me how can I get the three values of a particular row?

SOLUTION:
As Lurker pointed out in a comentary the solution is Subitems

```
listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[..]
```

Comment: Do you binding a List<someType> to your list view?

Comment: Did you try `listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[...]`? It's documented in the `ListView` documentaiton.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting SubItem from listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473701/getting-subitem-from-listview)

Comment: @lurker I think that is it. I am experimenting now.